# How to change width of centre column to fixed 1000 pixels w/o breaking fluid left and fluid right columns

Tags: css

```
#left-side-outer {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-400px;

}
#left-side{
    margin-right:400px;
    background-color: #FF9900;
    background: transparent url('../images/grass_pattern.png') repeat-x bottom !important;
    height: 82px;
}

#right-side-outer {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    margin-left:-401px;
    height: 82px;
}
#right-side {
    margin-left:400px;
    height: 82px;
    background-color: #FF9900;
    background: transparent url('../images/grass_pattern_red.png') repeat-x bottom !important;
    background: none;
}

#center-column {
    width:800px;
    height: 82px;
    float:left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    background: transparent url('../images/grass_pattern.png') repeat-x bottom !important;
    background: none;

}
```

My html:

```
 <div id="left-side-outer">
            <div id="left-side">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center-column">adsfadsfadfs</div>

        <div id="right-side-outer">
            <div id="right-side">
            </div>
        </div>
```

How do I make this work the if the width of the centre column is 1000 pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all `-400` to `-500`, all `400` to `500`, and `401` to `501`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `400px` references to `500px` if you are going to increase the width from `800px` to `1000px`